# sql statement for multiple fk columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables. The table A contains 3 columns referencing the id of table B. How do I write a select statement showing all names of table B referenced by table A.

Take a look it will explain itself pretty well:

table a is like this

```
----------------------
aid | bfk1 | bfk2 | bfk3
-----------------------
1   | 1    | 3    | 4
2   | 1    | 4    | 4
3   | 1    | 4    | 4
```

table b holds names

```
----------------------
bid | name
-----------------------
1   | test1  
2   | test2    
3   | test3
4   | test4
```

how to show all data from table a with names of table b. What sql statement do I need to achive this?
thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Hint:  `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the same table 3 times with different alias names

```
select a.aid,
       b1.name as b_name_1,
       b2.name as b_name_2,
       b3.name as b_name_3
from tableA a
left join tableB b1 on a.bfk1 = b1.bid
left join tableB b2 on a.bfk2 = b2.bid
left join tableB b3 on a.bfk3 = b3.bid
```

Comment: could you explain me why is that so?

Comment: Because you used 3 different columns and your table design is not normalized.

Comment: what you mean with not normalized?

Comment: It means there are database design rules. Following the fundamental ones is called normalizing the design.

Comment: tell me more please what are those normalizing design?

Comment: Currently it is not.

Comment: sure it is, what shall be different?

Comment: Thumb rule: If your column names contain numbers then you are doing something wrong.